# Why may "no DTD found" LXML parser error happen?

Tags: python, xml

Anybody knows what are the possible reasons for the following error message being printed by python lxml module?

```
enter code here`line 16470: PCDATA invalid Char value 31

alidation failed: no DTD found !, line 1, column 46
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because there was ASCII code 31 inside some tag's text on the specified line indeed.
After removal works properly.